# iphone: rotation in mpmovieplayercontroller?

Tags: iphone, ipad, rotation, mpmovieplayercontroller, cgaffinetransform

I have a small view on top of an mpmovieplayercontroller. When it is not fullscreen, I am able to adjust the frame of the view to the orientation (when the device rotates). But when I enter fullscreen mode, alothough I manage to present the view, I'm no longer able to maintain the correct frame when the device rotates. It looks like in fullscreen mode, the system simply using CGAffineTransformRotate on the status bar and the moviePlayer. How can I apply this CGAffineTransformRotate to rotate my view correctly?

---

EDIT:

Ok, so I updated the code to rotate 90% in the X axis after a change in orientation of the mpmovieplayercontroller but the view simply disappears after the first rotate. Here is my code:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{


     float   angle = M_PI / 2;  //rotate 180°, or 1 π radians
     theView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);


    [self changePositionBasedOnOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation]; //here we change the frame of the view


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,

So the best way to overlay the mpmovieplayercontroller in fullscreen is to it like that:

```
[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:mySubview]
```

It's a bit hacky, but legitimate. It gives you an easy way to deal with rotations (instead of using transformations).

Comment: That is not the best way but a possible way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this would necessarily be the *correct* way to do it (I guess you're adding a subview to the `MPMoviePlayerController` view?), but what you seem to be after is a callback to when the movie player rotates in fullscreen so you can adjust your own custom views.

You could register for rotation notifications on your custom view, which can then adjust itself every time it receives a callback. You register for rotation notifications as follows:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(layoutViewForOrientation:)
    name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
    object:nil];
```

You should remember to `endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` and remove your notification observer when you're done with the fullscreen mode.

Comment: +1 for correct answer. One addition though - for maintaining the correct dimensions to your custom subview, simply apply its original frame again AFTER applying the affine transformation (no need to account for switched coordinates at that point).

Comment: Yeah it's clear to me how to detect orientation changes. My Problem is with the transformations. Can you please post some code on how to actually rotate the view based on rotating the mpmovieplayercontroller (in full screen)?

Comment: How you rotate the view would depend on its content, but you'd probably want to a) check the current orientation, and then b) rotate that view using a transformation in the appropriate direction. If you're not sure how to apply the transformation itself check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242424/how-to-rotate-a-layer-view-e-g-just-like-you-would-in-enigmo