# Play Landscape Video in iOS8 with Landscape Correct Statusbar Inside Portrait App

Tags: xcode, video, ios8, orientation, mpmovieplayercontroller

Portrait App, loads video that displays in landscape.

in iOS7 all works fine (minor fix this is iOS6 too) but in iOS8 the statusbar, although showing in landscape actually shows at the size of a portrait statusbar so it only occupies the top left hand 60% of the video (if holding device in landscape).

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [planTitleLabel setText:[[ProgrammeHandler sharedHandler]
                             stringForElement:kPlanStringElementPlanTitle
                             onDay:0 inPlan:selectedPlan]];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return 0;
}

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];


    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] < 7.0) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:FALSE];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:TRUE withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
    }else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 8.0 && [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] < 9.0) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:TRUE];
    }


    NSString *moviePath = [[ProgrammeHandler sharedHandler] pathForAsset:kAssetVideoIntro onDay:0 forPlan:selectedPlan];
    CGSize screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    [whiteFadeView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenBounds.width, screenBounds.height)];

    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
    [[moviePlayer view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
    [moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill];
    //For viewing partially.....
    moviePlayer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    [moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill];
    [movieView setAlpha:0];

    [moviePlayer.view setFrame:[movieView frame]];
    moviePlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [movieView addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [moviePlayer play];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playbackFinished:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(hideControl)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:moviePlayer];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:0.50f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{[movieView setAlpha:1];} completion:^(BOOL fin){ }];
}

- (void) hideControl {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerNowPlayingMovieDidChangeNotification
                                                  object:moviePlayer];
    [moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
}
```

I did see this question but don't think it applies in my case.
[iphone: rotation in mpmovieplayercontroller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528613/iphone-rotation-in-mpmovieplayercontroller)

Does any one know how to restore the statusbar to it's fullscreen 'width'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after looking over this again today I noticed that there was an error that iOS7 seems happy with but it was correctly throwing an error in iOS8. For anyone else with the same issue:

The fix is simply to apply the transformation to the moviePlayer itself rather than the subview. e.g.

replace
    moviePlayer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
with
    movieView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);

Comment: Thanks,Helped me a lot.